# Why can't I use the prefix operator in front of a function call?

Tags: javascript, prefix-operator

When I run `++this.get('votes')`, I get the following error message

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation.
```

I got the same error message with `++(this.get('votes'))`.

I was able to fix the problem with `this.get('votes') + 1` but I can't figure out why the prefix operator doesn't work.

Why shouldn't `this.get('votes')` evaluate to 0 and then become 1 and return the value 1?

---

Original code in context:

```
var Comment = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(message) {
     this.set({votes: 0, message: message});
  },
  upvote: function(){
    // Set the `votes` attribute to the current vote count plus one.
    this.set('votes', ++this.get('votes')); 
  }
}
var comment = new Comment('This is a message');
comment.upvote();
```

Comment: @mu-is-too-short I was looking for a dupe and can't find one right now and I'm thinking that this question should be stripped of irrelevant Backbone to be useful to others.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I was looking for a duplicate too but couldn't find one. I don't know how comfortable I am with rewriting someone's question to "Why is `++f()` a `ReferenceError`?". I think dropping the `backbone.js` tag would be fair as this isn't really about Backbone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying problem is that you can't assign to `this.get('votes')`; i.e, something of the form:

```
f() = x;
```

is not valid because `f()` isn't an lvalue.

If you check the [specs](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-prefix-increment-operator), you'll see that `++x` is roughly the same as:

```
x = x + 1
```

and you can't assign a value to a function call. You're really trying to say:

```
this.get('votes') = this.get('votes') + 1;
```

and that's not JavaScript.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the spec. Why wouldn't this.get('votes') evaluate to 0 before it tries to add 1?

Comment: Because `++` tries to modify its operand and a method call isn't a modifiable value. Your problem occurs before `this.get('votes')` gets called so there isn't a chance for it to evaluate to anything. Keep in mind that `++x` is shorthand for `x = x + 1` so your `++f()` is trying to say `f() = f() + 1`.

Comment: So you're basically just saying you can only use ++ in front of a variable?